# How to initialise a shared pointer that is a class member in the constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I have a shared pointer but am not able to initialise it to 0.

Here is my code:

```
class ROSThreadObjTest
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> var;
    std::vector<ROSThreadObj> threads;
    std::vector<void *(*)(void *)> functions;

public:

    ROSThreadObjTest():(new int(0))
    {
    }
```

How can I modify my constructor to set the value of var to 0 when the constructor is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allocate a new pointer and set that `int` to `0` then you can use `std::make_shared`

```
ROSThreadObjTest() : var(std::make_shared<int>(0)) {}
```

If rather you want to set the pointer to `nullptr` (if that's what you meant by `0`), then you don't have to do anything special in the constructor, as that is what the `shared_ptr` will be default initialized to.